# Hibernate Commit Before Method

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7

Looking for a way to force Hibernate to commit all in-memory transactions before we execute a method in Java EE. We send out an email to the user when they perform certain actions, and we had an issue the other day where the user received an email, but the server containing the data filled up and Hibernate wasn't able to commit the transaction. A rare case, sure, but we want to avoid it in the future. So, the workflow should run as follows:

1. User performs action
2. Hibernate commits action to database
3. System sends email to user

If step 2 fails, the application call should fail so it doesn't send the email and the user is notified. We're running Hibernate with JPA on a WildFly server, if that helps. I have a solution using the flush() method of the entity manager, but I know those transactions can still be rolled back. I also know we could use `@Transactional`, but I was hoping to implement logic in the method which sends the email instead of outside methods so that it would do the same thing any time the method was called and we wouldn't have to worry about forgetting it later.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make sure that a transaction ultimately commits is to, well, *actually commit* the transaction. This means that you should commit the transaction *first*, and only perform the irreversible actions (like sending out notifications) *once the transaction is complete*.

This, of course, introduces an at-most-once delivery semantics to your email notification functionality, because the system might still fail in between #2 and #3. You'll want to switch to at-least-once to make sure the email notification **eventually** gets sent for each completed transaction.

The simplest solution would be to introduce a table to serve as a queue for outgoing emails (or, alternatively, a boolean `email_sent` status column added to your business entity), coupled with a background job that picks up all pending notifications, sends the emails, and marks the notifications as complete.

To sum up, the scenario should be like this

1. User performs action
2. Your app performs the necessary business logic and saves changes in a transaction
3. **In the same transaction**, you add a row to an `outgoing_notifications` table
4. One of two things happen:

- (happy path) The transaction gets commited, the job is done, and the email is scheduled to be sent
- (alternative path) The transaction commit fails (and so, the creation of a new row in `outgoing_notifications` is also reverted), therefore no email will be sent

A background, periodic task then:

1. Reads the `outgoing_notifications` table
2. Sends the outgoing emails
3. Deletes the rows corresponding to successfully dispatched email notifications

Instead of using a table for `outgoing_notifications`, of course, you can use another solution, like a persistent message/task queue (provided that it can participate in the original transaction when receiving the new task). However, the above solution I believe is the most reliable and dead simple.